# Java 8 dates/times in Drools - performance vs. java.util.Date?

Tags: java, date, drools, localdate

I'm exploring using Drools with fact objects whose dates/time are Java 8 objects (`OffsetDateTime`, `OffsetTime` and `LocalDate`). I understand that Drools prefers `java.util.Date` - boo! - so given a fact class

```
public class Fact {
  private LocalDate date;
  ...
}
```

then this form doesn't work:

```
rule "Date is 12-FEB (native)"
dialect "mvel"
  when
    Fact( date == "2019-02-12" )
  then
    insert(drools.rule.name);
  end
```

but either of these forms does work:

```
rule "Date is 12-FEB (parse)"
dialect "mvel"
  when
    Fact( date == LocalDate.parse("2019-02-12") )
  then
    insert(drools.rule.name);
  end

rule "Date is 12-FEB (of)"
dialect "mvel"
  when
    Fact( date == LocalDate.of(2019, 2, 12) )
  then
    insert(drools.rule.name);
  end
```

So my question is, are the `LocalDate` objects baked into the `KieContainer` once, or are they re-created every time I call `KieContainer.newKieSession(...)`?

In other words, is there a performance hit in using Java 8 dates/times this way over `java.util.Date`?